# what is the significance of coerce in python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Being a newbie to python/pandas, just curious to know the significance/use of "coerce" in pandas syntax.

Is it only used in case of conversion(i would rather say force-full conversion) or it has some use cases in any other places.

Thanks in Adv.(An example will be highly valuable).

Comment: Can you explain what you don't understand from the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) as they seem pretty clear to me

Comment: try example here:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html   Hopefully makes sense although it doesn't really spell things out.

Comment: in a nutshell, for `pd.to_numeric()`, `errrors='raise'` is the default and will generate an error on something like `[1,2,'apple']`.  Setting errors to 'ignore' means the problem values will not be converted at all.  Setting errors to 'coerce' will force the column to float and problem values to NaN.